# Umbraco : Active directory implementation

Tags: security, umbraco

I'm looking to implement a higher amount of security to the CMS. So, when the site is live on the public domain, the site should check if the user is logged into our company network and is part of a certain group related to the site.

This is to prevent anyone just accessing the CMS Admin login page.

Is this possible? If so, does anyone have any good sites with tutorials or tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Umbraco? 4 or 5?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options here. If your company is running on one or more known IP addresses, you can restrict access to the "/umbraco/" folder using IIS. [See here](http://technicians-blog.kingcomputer.com.au/restrict-website-access-in-iis7-5-by-ip-address/) for how to do that.

The other option would be to write your own user provider for the back office. I believe that you can swap out the default one for one of your own if you like. I don't think there's much documentation for how to do that though. If you look in the umbraco projects library on our.umbraco.org, there are some examples of creating a front end user provider though, that you might be able to adapt for the back office.

Answer (score 0):

This was simpler than I thought, it took less than 30 minutes to implement this.

Here is a page with very useful instructions:
http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/membership-providers/active-directory-membership-provider